# TabIndex changed to Enter for all forms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabindex

How can i change TabIndex from "tab" to "enter" for all forms in my win application. I know i can use event for every textbox like:

```
If (Keys.Enter Then) {
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
}
```

but i don't want to do this 1000 times. Can i make this by default for all textboxes and forms?

Comment: I would suggest that doing this is a bad idea, you are introducing non standard behavior and as a user i would find this confusing.

Comment: Why don't you catch the event of keyDown on the enter key then deal with that according to some constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to enable forms [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property. Then you'll be able to handle keystroke before controls get it

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(Keys.Enter == e.KeyCode) 
    {
       SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
       e.Handled = true;//set to false if you need that textbox gets enter key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind all your textbox to the event "validation" (or something like that) and then call the same method which do the jump :)