# Can we convert the following if statements to a single switch?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 text boxes (but in the real scenario there are more than 3 text boxes), each of them is wired to a single event handler below.

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (tb.Equals(textBox1)) textBox2.Focus();
        if (tb.Equals(textBox2)) textBox3.Focus();
        if (tb.Equals(textBox3)) button1.Focus();
    }
}
```

When a user press enter key, the focus will be moved to the next text box. I want to avoid using hard-coded string constants when using `switch` so I am forced to use `if` as given above.

My question is: Is there any possibility to use `switch` but without using hard-code string constants?

### Edit

I don't want to write something like below because I hate hard-coded constant values.

```
switch (tb.Name)
{
    case "textboxnameone":
        textBox2.Focus();
        break;
    case "textboxnametwo":
        textBox3.Focus();
        break;
    case "textboxnamethree":
        button1.Focus();
        break;
}
```

Comment: [Use `SelectNextControl`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087786/press-enter-to-move-to-next-control)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here:
<strike>[TabIndex changed to Enter for all forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254835/tabindex-changed-to-enter-for-all-forms-in-c-sharp)</strike>
[How to send focus to control with tabindex lower than current control in C# windows form application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634825/how-to-send-focus-to-control-with-tabindex-lower-than-current-control-in-c-sharp)

You can accomplish this behavior in a much cleaner way using that solution and TabIndex.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: +1 I don't think the OP should do that, BUT this answer does answer his question.

Comment: I was also going to mention this thread, in which the accepted answer describes this concept without using SendKeys(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634825/how-to-send-focus-to-control-with-tabindex-lower-than-current-control-in-c-sharp

Comment: @CurtisRutland nice one too.

Comment: @CurtisRutland Agreed.  `Control.SelectNextControl()` is a better approach than `SendKey`. I edited my answer but do know that I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @CurtisRutland - That's definitely a great solution to this problem. You should make your comment on this answer into an answer all on its own, so that we can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

If set the *TabIndex* property of the controls properly, you can use it.

```
TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

var dict = this.Controls.Cast<Control>()
               .ToDictionary(c => c.TabIndex, c);

dict[tb.TabIndex + 1].Focus();
```

Comment: preferably check TabStop as well

Comment: @CodeMocker Because last item to get focus is a button.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you define at the start of your form this Dictionary

```
Dictionary<TextBox, Action>dicFocus = new Dictionary<TextBox,Action>();
dicFocus.Add(t1, () => t2.Focus());
dicFocus.Add(t2, () => t3.Focus());
dicFocus.Add(t3, () => t1.Focus());
```

where t1,t2,t3 etc.. are the textboxes that have the common keypress event while the Action is the method that you want to execute when the keypress event happens.

Now your KeyPress could be writtes as

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
    if(dicFocus.Keys.Contains(tb) 
        dicFocus[tb].Invoke();
}
```

This approach will keep always the focus on the control you need also if during development someone changes the taborder of your controls. Also the whole affair is kept in a specific location of your form and could be easily adjusted if the need arises for a different order

Answer (score 0):

Give them sequential values for TabIndex, and in the event, check the TabIndex of the sender and just focus the next one each time. If you get to a too high number, loop back to the first.

Alternatively, without using TabIndex, put the participating controls in a list and use the same concept.

*answered from mobile, please excuse